# How to prevent PineApp from blocking mail?

Tags: spam-prevention

My email provided just installed [PineApp](http://www.pineapp.com/) for mail blocking. The thing is, I don't *want* it to block anything. At least, I want to have a "only block by blacklist" policy.

Is there a way to 'tell' PineApp that?

<sub>There's some web interface to manage quarantined messages, but it doesn't look like it has a settings section where I can do this.</sub>